# How to apply changes to the current class in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I've read similar questions and tried different methods, but nothing seems to work. I have a Liking system. A heart image which switches between liked (filled heart icon) and unliked (Plain bordered heart icon).

The problem is, when I click on the like/heart button, all the other records' heart icon turns to liked state. The same goes with the like count. When I like a post, all the post's like count becomes the same.

Also, I'm running an AJAX request to get the likes count. When I try to output the likes and increment/decrement if they like/unlike, the output is weird. It goes to -1 or 01 etc.

This is my main.blade.php :

```
<span class="activityLikes">
    <input type="hidden" class="activityIdHidden" value="{{ $activity->activity_id }}">
    <a class="likeBtn">
    @if(Auth::user()->hasLikedActivity($activity))
        <img class="likeImg likeTrue" src="IMG/icons/likeTrue.png" alt="likes">
    @else
        <img class="likeImg likeFalse" src="IMG/icons/like.png" alt="likes">
    @endif
    </a><span class="likesCount">{{ $activity->likes->count() }}</span>
</span>
```

This is my main.js file :

```
$('.likeBtn').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var likeCount = 0;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: './mainView/getLikeCount',
        data: {activityId: activityId},
        success: function(data){
            likeCount = data;
        },
        error: function(e){
            console.log(JSON.stringify("Exception: " + e));
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './mainView/postlike',
        data: {activityId : activityId, user_id: user_id},
        success: function(data){
            if(data == "deleted"){
                $('.likeImg').attr('src', 'IMG/icons/like.png');
                $('.likesCount').text(likeCount - 1);
            } else if(data == "liked"){
                $('.likeImg').attr('src', 'IMG/icons/likeTrue.png');
                $('.likesCount').text(likeCount + 1);
            }
        },
        error: function(e){
            console.log(JSON.stringify("Exception: " + e));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you update every image that has the `.likeImg` class on the success event.

Can you try the following code ?

```
$('.likeBtn').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var likeCount = 0;
    // element to update is `this` (the element that had been clicked)
    var elementToUpdate = $(this).children('img'); 

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: './mainView/getLikeCount',
        data: {activityId: activityId},
        success: function(data){
            likeCount = data;
        },
        error: function(e){
            console.log(JSON.stringify("Exception: " + e));
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './mainView/postlike',
        data: {activityId : activityId, user_id: user_id},
        success: function(data){
            if(data == "deleted"){
                elementToUpdate.attr('src', 'IMG/icons/like.png');
                elementToUpdate.text(likeCount - 1);
            } else if(data == "liked"){
                elementToUpdate.attr('src', 'IMG/icons/likeTrue.png');
                elementToUpdate.text(likeCount + 1);
            }
        },
        error: function(e){
            console.log(JSON.stringify("Exception: " + e));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The image just vanishes when I use this code and the problem still exists. It's only liking the first post

Comment: I think the reason why $(this) will not work here is because $(this) would point to the `<a>` and you're trying to set its `attr('src', '...')`

Comment: I updated my post. this was the a tag but you needed to update the img inside it. I fixed it by adding `.children('img')` after a bit of searching the jQuery docs (sorry, I'm not used to jQuery anymore)

Comment: That worked, but when I refresh, the like increments for the first one only. Even if click like on the second one. I'l take a look at my Controller

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it does not guarantee that the second Ajax request will come back with its response *after* the first one comes back. Although it might work in 99% of the cases like that, it is not guaranteed.

Comment: @trincot You're absolutely right. I focused on the main issue without properly checking the code. Your solution should be the valid one !

Answer (score 2):

You should chain your Ajax calls, and get the count *after* updating the "like" status, like this:

```
function errHandler(e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify("Exception: " + e));
} 

$('.likeBtn').on('click', function(e){
    var activityId = +$(this).siblings(".activityIdHidden").val(),
        $img = $("img", this),
        $likes = $(this).siblings(".likesCount");

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './mainView/postlike',
        data: {activityId : activityId, user_id: user_id},
        error: errHandler
    }).then(function(data){
        $img.attr('src', data === "deleted" ? 'IMG/icons/like.png' : 'IMG/icons/likeTrue.png');
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: './mainView/getLikeCount',
            data: {activityId: activityId},
            error: errHandler
        });
    }).then(function(data){
        $likes.text(data);
    });
});
```